# Excel saving csv as semi colon issue

Tags: excel

When I save my excel in csv, it has semicolon as separator. I have to open and replace everytime to get the coma separted file.

So I tried this option given below but it was already a coma.

```
Click on the Start menu.
Type control panel.
Click on Control Panel (Desktop app).
Select Clock, Language, and Region.
Click Region.
Select Additional settings in the pop-up window.
Change the List separator to comma.
```

Then I saw this option on google. But there is no such 'Use system settings' in my Excel(O365 installed version 2103)

```
Select File > Options > Advanced.
Tick the check box 'Use system settings'.
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My decimal was also coma, this prevented the csv from using coma as delimiter. Once decimal got changed to dot, it worked(saved as coma separated)